# Granting permission with a condition to check requestor's compute hostname

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a GCP Storage bucket that I've granted Storage Object Admin to a Compute service account and it works fine. But I would like to use a condition (available when you edit the member's permission in the bucket) to restrict some of the Computes by hostname.

Can this be done? If yes, what would the syntax be like?

Thank you!

Regards,

Mike Yeap

Answer (score 0):

[The list of supported atributes](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-attribute-reference) suggests that this might be possible with [access levels attribute](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/conditions-attribute-reference#access-levels), but needs testing and it is in private beta yet.

As a workaround I suggest using [custom service accounts](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances) granted granular permissions with your compute engine instances.